# copy bones animations to other?

Tags: 3dsmax

I have two characters rigged by skin modifier

the first character has an animation , but the second hasn't

the problems :

> - the bones in both characters not the same names and not the same size  either.
> - the rotation pivot and the bones count are different too .

are there any way to copy the animations from the first character to the other ?

even though if I need to use other program instead of **3dsmax**

thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to solve the 'retargeting' problem. This problem has been studied in animation and gaming industry for quite a few years.

To my knowledge, there are at least two ways to solve your problem.

The first is to use Unity. When you import a human character into Unity, the engine will try to identify major bones of it. If succeed, Unity will be able to 'copy' any animation of one character to another. Of course the animation can then be exported for your future use. The identifying step can also be done manually.

The second is to use Autodesk HumanIK package. Autodesk integrates HumanIK in Maya. Just google 'Maya Retargeting', there are many tutorials on this topic.